# Server is not configured for RPC

Tags: sql-server

Looking for my job history I foudn the error below:

```
06/18/2018 00:00:01,MBS_Lojas_ExportaMR_OutrasLojas,Error,1,WIN-VRT-01\SQL2008,MBS_Lojas_ExportaMR_OutrasLojas,Passo1,,Executed as user: WIN-VRT-01\integracao. Server 'x.y.z' is not configured for RPC. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7411).  The step failed.,01:11:15,16,7411,,,,0
```

I have this linked server with the option RPC and RPC Out with the values assigned to true.

In the job I have this

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'x.y.z', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'x.y.z', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

I can't find out why is this happening and none of the solutions posted for this error could help me to debug this issue.

Comment: Did you link the remote server? Seems you can see linked servers with `SELECT * FROM sys.servers`

Comment: I tested the connection with success.

Comment: With that quey I see the server and the option "is_linked" and "is_rpc_out_enabeld" with value 1

Answer (score 29):

I made RPC and RPC out fields as True (as shown in the image below). Logged out of SSMS and logged back in and it worked.

[image: Linked Server Properties]

Comment: you did not spell out where you got to this dialog

Answer (score 22):

You need to enable `RPC Out` in Linker Server Properties on the Calling Server.

**Don't enable `RPC`** unless you want the linked server to be able to make calls to your server.

[image: Enable RDP Out in Linked Server Properties]

Answer (score 5):

Just to add the steps to open the Properties window.
In the SMSS calling server, expand Server Objects -> expand Linked Servers -> right click linked server -> properties