# Can I run SQL Server Job through Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, linked-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

I have two SQL Server machines:

1. `SqlServer-1`
2. `SqlServer-2`

I have a job created on `SqlServer-1` named `RunExeFile`.

`SqlServer-2` can access `SqlServer-1` through a linked server.

Can I start the job `RunExeFile` from a stored procedure on `SqlServer-2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can run this in your stored procedure on `SqlServer-2` against linked Server `LinkedServer1`:

```
EXEC LinkedServer1.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'RunExeFile';
```

You need to configure RPC and ensure the calling security context is set:

[image]

Comment: Server 'SQLServer-1' is not configured for RPC

Comment: so configure it for RPC : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907968/server-is-not-configured-for-rpc

Comment: Oh yes I did that, but now I'm getting another error

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_start_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: then that's another question.......It's saying you need to configure the user that the linked server call runs as. That's a different problem.